# How to use os.path.join() when finding many files

Tags: python, excel, os.path

I want to find and open 500 Excel files so I can edit them. I was told it was possible to use the `os.path.join()` to get them simultaniously since they are in one folder. When I used:

```
file_location = os.path.join("C:\Users\A12345\Desktop\Folder_name","file_1.xlsm)
```

it worked but now I want to find and open all of them. Anyone have an idea how to do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

All `os.path.join()` does is concatenate a path and a filename, i.e. it abstracts out the directory separation character for you. It has nothing to do with "getting" files.

You're going to have to use something like [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to get the filenames:

```
xlsms = glob.glob('C:\Users\A12345\Desktop\Folder_name\*.xlsm')
```

Then you can feed those to Excel I guess, using [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

```
cmd = "msexcel.exe %s" % " ".join(xlsms)
os.system(cmd)
```

Here I assume that Excel is available as `msexcel.exe`, and that it accepts hundreds of filenames on the command line.

Comment: What does this do? cmd = "msexcel.exe %s" % " ".join(xlsms)
os.system(cmd) What is meant by "feed" to excel?

Comment: @Roslund It merely runs Excel from the command line, passing it the filenames as arguments. I just assumed you can do that, without checking.